# How to write database errors to a text file PHP

Tags: php, database

ok this is probably pretty simple but for some reason I can't do it. I have an insert statement and once the query is executed the die() response shows to the users.

I truly don't want that response going to the user. I would like for this response to be written to a text file. Can somebody please help me with this.

If I have `$result = mssql_query($query) or die();`
How can I capture what is in `$result`. if I print it out it's a 1 and normally of course if you're trying to get data from a query you search parse through an array to get this out but I'm not parsing data I just want the error.

Comment: $result = mssql_query($query) or error_log('My custom error message')/trigger_error('My error', E_USER_ERROR)/throw new Exception('My error message')/file_put_contents('error.txt','my error') take your pick

Comment: `$result = mysql_query(...) or log_to_file_then_die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
$result = mssql_query($query);
if(!$result) {
    file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', mssql_get_last_message());
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `or die()` part, [mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php) ex :

```
$result = mssql_query($query);
if(!$result) {
    $error_message = mssql_get_last_message();
    //write $error_message somewhere
}
```

Comment: this still only returns 1

Answer (score 0):

`mssql_query($query)` returns boolean, thats why its 1 means `TRUE.`
finally you can write as,

```
$result = mssql_query($query);
$row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];//your output
mssql_free_result($result);
```

and answer to your *titled question* is already given by @AbraCadaver.

Comment: What do you mean by that.?

Comment: I've tried the above. This is the reason why I'm writing. this is the error I get
SuccessPHP Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Transaction (Process ID 69) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (severity 13) PHP Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed  
PHP Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource
PHP Warning: mssql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\KU\test-test.php on line 531

Comment: the other warning I get is PHP Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\KU\test-test.php on line 529 PHP Warning: mssql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\KU\test-test.php on line 531

Comment: first run your query on the server if its OK then check syntax of functions that are getting you 'supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL... error', also use SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY { LOW | NORMAL | HIGH }  for fixing deadlock  error,

Comment: this query works. I've been using it for many years and haven't had a problem...the problem is this it's just an insert stmt and to use mssql_fetch_array is probably not the answer because it's not returning anything it's just an insert. That's the dilemma in my head for that logic. Maybe I'm wrong but those are my thoughts and possibly why that error is returned concerning mssql_fetch_array not being a valid MS SQL-result resource